# How to set environment variables for a User-managed notebook in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-notebook

I am trying to set some environment variables for a user managed notebook in google cloud Vertex AI. I don't want to set this from a jupyter notebook itself because I want these environment variables to be available to anyone who opens a jupyter notebook from this notebook instance. This is what I have tried so far but nothing has worked:

1. I have an existing user managed notebook. I ssh'd into the notebook vm and then set a environment variable, `export TEST_VAR=TEST_VARIABLE_WAS_SET` there. However, when I open a jupyter notebook from the console and do `os.environ["TEST_VAR"]`, it gives a key error. So, I am assuming that this has something to do with the fact that the jupyter lab session that Vertex AI starts is in a different shell session or something similar. I also tried to add the following two metadata keys to the vm, and then restarted the vm, but it did not work:

`gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${INSTANCE_NAME} --metadata startup-script-url=$GCS_BUCKET_NAME/script.sh`

where script.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TEST_VAR=TEST_VARIABLE_WAS_SET
```

AND

`gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${INSTANCE_NAME} --metadata container-env-file=$GCS_BUCKET_NAME/notebook-env.txt`

where notebook-env.txt is

```
TEST_VAR=TEST_VARIABLE_WAS_SET
```

2. I also tried to create a new instance of a user managed notebook from the cloud console. In that I tried to provide a script in the "Select a script to run after creation" and also through the "Metadata" option by providing, the key as `startup-script-url` and the value as the script location on google cloud storage. The script was the same startup script earlier.

So, how do I achieve this, for existing user managed notebooks and when I create new ones?

Comment: Does [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/notebooks/environments/create) help you? It describes how you can create/set an environment for a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the public documentation that I shared with you a couple days ago, what you would need to do to set your environment variables correctly and without a problem is to run your script (using `--post-startup-script`) after the notebook instance fully boots up. The path must be a URL or Cloud Storage path as mentioned
**(gs://path-to-file/file-name)**.

Consider below approach as an example;

```
–-post-startup-script=$GCS_BUCKET_NAME/script.sh
```